# Using `replace` with Node.js function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to write some code which will take a string containing partial URLs like `google.com` and will transform them into a full URL like `https://google.com`.

I'm very inexperienced with Node.js and I'm still trying to get my head around the idea of asynchronicity.

I'm attempting to use callbacks instead of stuff like promises and async/await, and in my head the following code should work:

```
exports.rectifyDocumentURLs = function(baseUrl, document, callback) {
    callback(null,
        document.replace(url_patterns.any, (match) => {
            return exports.fixUrl(match, baseUrl, (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err, null)
                }

                return res
            })
        })
    )
}
```

`url_patterns.any` is some regex code which will match any type of code, and the function `exports.fixUrl` is a function which will take a partial URL and return it in its full form.

When I run the code like so

```
exports.rectifyDocumentURLs("https://google.com", "google.com", (rectifyErr, rectifyRes) => {
    console.log(rectifyRes)
})
```

The current code just returns `undefined`, but the `res` of the `fixUrl` function returns the correct result, `http://google.com`.

I understand that this a lot like many of the questions on here, but after extensive research and many tries and rewrites, I believe this may be the only way to fix the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your function `rectifyDocumentURLs()` is all messed up.

The idea of the callback is that when something will happen asynchronously you don't know when it will be finished. So you pass it a function, when it's done it calls the function you passed it with the result you want. Typically functions that take callbacks never return a meaningful value -- the value is passed to the callback. In `rectifyDocumentURLs()` you are calling the callback immediately, then calling it again with the callback of another function and also returning a (maybe undefined) value. That's just not going to work.

Here's a more standard approach:

```
exports.rectifyDocumentURLs = function(baseUrl, document, callback) {
    // it looks like document.replace is async and takes a callback 
    // when it's done it will pass its result to the callback as match  
    document.replace(url_patterns.any, (match) => {
        // you don't need return the result of a function that takes a callback
       // it will pass its result to the callback
        exports.fixUrl(match, baseUrl, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                callback(err, null)
            } else {
                // now that you have res and no error, call the callback
                // you passed to rectifyDocumentURLs()
                // this value will be the rectifyRes in the function you passed
                callback(null, res)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Of course, as others pointed out, there is already a lot of existing code for handling URLS, but this is a good exercise.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the url module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) who provide utilities for URL resolution and parsing.

```
const url = require('url');
const myURL = new URL('https://google.com');
console.log(myURL.host); // google.com
```